# razor output int to DOM and increment in same line

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Ok, this is really bugging me!

I'm trying to do the following in one line:

This works:

```
<h4>3.1.@skillSectionNumber SKILLS</h4>
{skillSectionNumber++;}
```

This doesn't work:

```
<h4>3.1.@skillSectionNumber++ SKILLS</h4>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<h4>3.1.@{Response.Write(skillSectionNumber++.ToString());} SKILLS</h4>
```

Cheers

---

My solution was this:

```
<h4>3.1.@(skillSectionNumber++) SKILLS</h4>
```

I was missing the parens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pre-increment approach.

```
@{ var skillSectionNumber = 10;}
<h4> 3.1.@(++skillSectionNumber) SKILLS </h4>
```

It basically first increase the value of you `skillSectionNumber` variable and then use it (for rendering)

Comment: Thanks, I was so close :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to use the `Response.Write`. You could just use the following:

```
 <h4>3.1.@{(skillSectionNumber++).ToString();} SKILLS</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending where you put the `++` will make the difference.

`skillSectionNumber++` does the incrementing last, and `++skillSectionNumber` does the incrementing first.

So in your scenario you can do the following:

```
<h4>3.1.@(++skillSectionNumber) SKILLS </h4>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know how the ++ works. I was just missing the parens.